# Client/server-communication in Texas Hold'em

Tags: java, client, communication

I am currently programming a Texas Hold'em LAN game in Java. My problem is how to do the client/server-communication.

Each time something happens at the table, the clients need to be informed of this so they can repaint their GUIs. Also when a players turn is up, they need to be able to fold, call etc.

How do I best implement this? I've looked at callbacks/RMI, but from what I've read, that may cause problems with firewalls(?)

Comment: If its a LAN game why are you worried about firewalls :)

Answer (score 2):

When you are concerned about firewalls, the best way would be to use HTTP, like a web browser. The benefits are:

- The protocol is well-known
- There are many client and server libraries available, which are well-tested
- HTTP is not restricted to web browsers. Any program can talk HTTP.

The downside is that *push* messages by the server are not commonly used. Of course you can just open an HTTP connection from each client that will wait for data from the server.

Comment: +1. Using HTTP and port 80 circumvents many firewall barriers. HTTPS and port 443 is even better since it is less likely to be intercepted and possibly reformatted by a proxy. RMI doesn't play well with firewalls because of the way it uses ephemeral ports.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the Java tutorials on sockets:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

An example client/server is given.